# bonecms laravel-captcha validator for hesto multi-auth login

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am using hesto/multi-auth for login.I want to add captcha for login and register.For that i am using bonecms/laravel-captcha.I Used validator for captcha on register.I need to add validator for the captcha on login Form.Where I want to add validator? How should I change my Login Controller?

For Register Form with Validator:

```
<div class="col-md-6">
   @captcha
   <input id="captcha" type="text" class="form-control" name="captcha">
</div>

On Register Controller
protected function validator(array $data) {
    return Validator::make($data, [
        'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:clients',
        'password' => 'required|min:6|confirmed',
        'captcha' => 'required|captcha',
    ]);
}
```

Login Form Code:

```
For Login Form view
<div class="col-md-6">
    @captcha
    <input id="captcha" type="text" class="form-control" name="captcha">
</div
```

I need to validate Captcha for login form.

Answer (score 2):

customize Login Validator for Admin Login.

Route login goes to LoginController::login() method. Add your validation rules to LoginController::login() method

```
public function login(Request $request){
    $this->validate($request, [
        'email'           => 'required|max:255|email',
        'password'           => 'required|confirmed',
        'captcha'        => 'required|captcha'
    ]);

    if (Auth::guard('admin')->attempt(['email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password])) {
        return redirect()->intended('/admin/home');
    } else {
        return redirect()->back();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add login method in your LoginController and customize it.
make sure you import Auth top on your Controller.

```
public function login(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'email'           => 'required|max:255|email',
        'password'           => 'required|confirmed',
        'captcha'        => 'required|captcha'
    ]);

    if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password])) {
        // Success
        return redirect()->intended('/dashboard');
    } else {
        // Go back on error (or do what you want)
        return redirect()->back();
    }

}
```